# Change class on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to acomplish this:

when i click on `box-btn`

1. Box `btn` will change icon
2. Text and title  will be different color
3. Box Image get some overlay

---

This change will be active until i click again, then will be restarted to the old classes.
Thank you

```
<div class="col-md-4 wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="main">
     <h2 class="box-title">TITLE</h2>
     <p class="box-text"></p>
     <div class="box-foot">
       <a href="">
         <div class="box-img"></div>
       </a>
       <span class="white-line-vertical"></span>
       <button type="submit" class="box-btn">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post what you tried so far?

Comment: This example should help you http://jsfiddle.net/geonunez/pWG2S/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

CSS

```
.clicked {
     color : #ececec; //whatever color you want to change to
 }
```

JS

```
$("button.box-btn").on("click", function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
   $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("btn-clicked");
   if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
     $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
     $(this).addClass("glyphicon-star-full");
   }else{
     $(this).removeClass("glyphicon-star-full");
     $(this).addClass("glyphicon-star-empty");
   }
})
```

Comment: i got syntax error on this line
if($(this).hasClass("clicked"){

Comment: Sorry i missed a `)` after that. I ll update my code.

Comment: Okej this work for box- btn , now:
Text and title will be different color
Box Image get some overlay

Should i add this clicked class in html, and add css clicked img-box, or?

Comment: I gave you the logic to achieve it. You should alter the css or the classes to your need.

Comment: just for your info, i am updating the code and also adding a class to the div with class `.main`. You can use css to add overlay and also change the color of title and text.